# How do you print the EXACT value of a floating point number?

Tags: c, algorithm, math, floating-point

First of all, this is not a floating point newbie question. I know results of floating point arithmetic (not to mention transcendental functions) usually cannot be represented exactly, and that most terminating decimals cannot be represented exactly as binary floating point numbers.

That said, each possible floating point value corresponds exactly to a diadic rational (a rational number `p/q` where `q` is a power of 2), which in turn has an exact decimal representation.

My question is: How do you find this exact decimal representation efficiently? `sprintf` and similar functions are usually only specified up to a number of significant digits to uniquely determine the original floating point value; they don't necessarily print the exact decimal representation. I know one algorithm I've used, but it's very slow, `O(e^2)` where `e` is the exponent. Here's an outline:

1. Convert the mantissa to a decimal integer. You can either do this by pulling apart the bits to read the mantissa directly, or you can write a messy floating point loop that first multiplies the value by a power of two to put it in the range 1<=x<10, then pulls off a digit at a time by casting to int, subtracting, and multiplying by 10.
2. Apply the exponent by repeatedly multiplying or dividing by 2. This is an operation on the **string** of decimal digits you generated. Every ~3 multiplications will add an extra digit to the left. Every single dividion will add an extra digit to the right.

Is this really the best possible? I doubt it, but I'm not a floating-point expert and I can't find a way to do the base-10 computations on the floating point representation of the number without running into a possibility of inexact results (multiplying or dividing by anything but a power of 2 is a lossy operation on floating point numbers unless you know you have free bits to work with).

Comment: In the end, I simply replaced my old base-10 code with base-1e9 and repeated multiplication/division by 2 with mult by 2^29 and div by 2^9 for most of the iterations followed by mult/div by 2 for the tail. The resulting code prints the smallest 80-bit `long double` in fairly negligible time, so I'm happy enough.

Comment: Jon Skeet has a [DoubleConverter class](http://yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/DoubleConverter.cs) that can print the exact decimal representations. It's written in C# but you can convert it to C http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732680/how-to-output-a-double-value-with-all-the-decimal-places-in-debugger-or-console

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This question has a bureaucratic part and an algorithmic part. A floating point number is stored internally as (2<sup>*e*</sup> × *m*), where *e* is an exponent (itself in binary) and *m* is a mantissa. The bureaucratic part of the question is how to access this data, but R. seems more interested in the algorithmic part of the question, namely, converting (2<sup>*e*</sup> × *m*) to a fraction (*a*/*b*) in decimal form. The answer to the bureaucratic question in several languages is `frexp` (which is an interesting detail that I didn’t know before today).

It is true that at first glance, it takes *O*(*e*<sup>2</sup>) work just to write 2<sup>*e*</sup> in decimal, and more time still for the mantissa.  But, thanks to the magic of the [Schönhage–Strassen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sch%C3%B6nhage%E2%80%93Strassen_algorithm) fast multiplication algorithm, you can do it in *Õ*(*e*) time, where the tilde means “up to log factors”. If you view Schönhage–Strassen as magic, then it’s not that hard to think of what to do. If *e* is even, you can recursively compute 2<sup>*e*/2</sup>, and then square it using fast multiplication. On the other hand if *e* is odd, you can recursively compute 2<sup>*e*−1</sup> and then double it. You have to be careful to check that there is a version of Schönhage–Strassen in base 10. Although it is not widely documented, it can be done in any base.

Converting a very long mantissa from binary to base 10 is not exactly the same question, but it has a similar answer. You can divide the mantissa into two halves, *m* = *a* × 2<sup>*k*</sup> + *b*.  Then recursively convert *a* and *b* to base 10, convert 2<sup>*k*</sup> to base 10, and do another fast multiplication to compute *m* in base 10.

The abstract result behind all of this is that you can convert integers from one base to another in *Õ*(*N*) time.

If the question is about standard 64-bit floating point numbers, then it’s too small for the fancy Schönhage–Strassen algorithm. In this range you can instead save work with various tricks. One approach is to store all 2048 values of 2<sup>*e*</sup> in a lookup table, and then work in the mantissa with asymmetric multiplication (in between long multiplication and short multiplication). Another trick is to work in base 10000 (or a higher power of 10, depending on architecture) instead of base 10. But, as R. points out in the comments, 128-bit floating point numbers already allow large enough exponents to call into question both lookup tables and standard long multiplication. As a practical matter, long multiplication is the fastest up to a handful of digits, then in a significant medium range one can use [Karatsuba multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm) or [Toom–Cook multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toom%E2%80%93Cook_multiplication), and then after that a variation of Schönhage–Strassen is best not just in theory but also in practice.

Actually, the big integer package [GMP](https://gmplib.org/manual/Binary-to-Radix.html) already has *Õ*(*N*)-time radix conversion, as well as good heuristics for which choice of multiplication algorithm. The only difference between their solution and mine is that instead of doing any big arithmetic in base 10, they compute large powers of 10 in base 2. In this solution, they also need fast division, but that can be obtained from fast multiplication in any of several ways.

Comment: Thanks for the link and the first answer with any theoretical content! It looks like [Toom-Cook](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toom%E2%80%93Cook_multiplication) might actually be the preferable algorithm for non-astronomical-exponents.

Comment: Very interesting.  Could you explain how using base 10000 speeds things up?

Comment: Steven: Using base 10000 speeds things up because it's 4 times faster than base 10 due to them both fitting in a machine word.

Comment: Don't get too excited: "As a rule of thumb, Karatsuba is usually faster when the multiplicands are longer than 320-640 bits." -http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm

Comment: @Gabe: That makes sense.  Base 10000 can be trivially converted to decimal, but speeds up the intermediate steps by lowering the number of digits.  I'm not sure how this compares to the BCD-based approaches, but it's certainly viable.

Comment: R.: Well, the adjective "astronomical" is a bit flat because there are various sizes of numbers for various purposes.  It is true that in a medium range you or a library might use Karatsuba or Toom-Cook, but actually both of them are similar to Schonhage-Strassen.

Comment: R: Even Toom-Cook and Karatsuba are too big for piddly little 64-bit floats. If you just wanted a faster implementation you would simply use a bigger base than 10 (1e2 for bytes, 1e4 for words, and 1e9 for ints) and do larger multiplies (e.g. do 1/3 as many multiplies by 8 or 1/16 as many multiplies by 65536).

Comment: Steven:  See for instance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469529/#1875697 .  For multiplication you wouldn't just want one digit to fit in a machine word, but also the product of two digits.

Comment: @Gabe, are you sure? A "64-bit" float involves ~1076-digit (decimal) arithmetic. An "80-bit" float involves ~16448-digit arithmetic.

Comment: R.: Actually the max 64-bit float in IEEE 754 has 309 decimal digits and a max 128-bit float has 4933 decimal digits.  Remember, there will be fewer decimal digits than binary digits.  But you're right that that is getting to the range of accelerated multiplciation algorithms.

Comment: You're thinking of cases where the exponent is positive. If it's negative, every time you decrement the exponent further you get an extra decimal place on the right (holding a '5') but it takes several exponent decrements to clear a decimal place on the left (e.g. 5->2->1->0). I overestimated but it seems you need roughly binary_exp*2/3 decimal digits, so ~700 digits for IEEE 754.

Comment: Oh, I missed a detail in the question.  I thought you wanted a decimal representation of the numerator and denominator of the fraction.  For the exact decimal of the fraction itself, I agree with your estimate.

Comment: R: Assuming you use 64-bit machine words (base 1e19), each double-precision float will only require 17 (or 37 for negative exponents) words at most to represent, and you could then multiply by 2^64 at a time, so you would only have to do 16 multiplies. Since that's just worst case, most conversions would require very few operations, so Karatsuba or Toom-3 wouldn't give you an advantage.

Comment: I was thinking 32-bit machine words which are still pretty much the norm. I could try making the code use `size_t` or another type that's essentially-guaranteed to be machine-word-sized instead of `uint32_t` with compile-time computations to determine the base that gets used, but it might be a bit of a pain.

Comment: @Greg: If I understand correctly, the "320-640 bits" does not apply to the "compact" floating point representation here but rather to the full expansion (whether decimal or otherwise).

Comment: Steven: I think that that's right.  However, it applies, because the question posed was about converting a floating point binary to a full decimal.  Actually Karatsuba in base 10 would become competitive sooner, because the advice about the threshold assumes a fast arithmetic unit in the CPU.

Comment: Schönhage-Strassen is vast overkill. The numbers of bits involved are far too small to ever need it. For 80 bit or 128 bit binary floats, you may need to use Karatsuba. In  my (fast) BigInteger implementation, it only gets faster than plain base-case multiplication at approx. 3200 bits, and above that, Toom-Cook (e.g. 3-way) at approx. 8200 bits. Schönhage-Strassen is for numbers with vastly more bits. Due to its large overhead, it is ssslllooowww for smaller numbers. I'd rather rely on GMP or similar. They choose the right algorithm depending on the number of bits.

Answer (score 18):

I see you’ve accepted an answer already, but here are a couple of open source implementations of this conversion you might want to look at:

1. David Gay’s `dtoa()` function in `dtoa.c`: https://www.netlib.org/fp/dtoa.c.
2. The function `___printf_fp()` in the `/stdio-common/printf_fp.c` file in Glibc (https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/glibc-2.11.2.tar.gz, for example).

Both will print as many digits as you ask for in a `%f`-type `printf`, as I’ve written about at:

- https://www.exploringbinary.com/print-precision-of-dyadic-fractions-varies-by-language/ and
- https://www.exploringbinary.com/print-precision-of-floating-point-integers-varies-too/.

Comment: Great answer! This is the type of thing I was looking for. I'll check out those sources.

Comment: Your blog is fantastic.  I'd seen a few posts on it earlier, but wasn't aware that the author exists here too :)

Comment: ISTM that David M. gay's implementation is a de facto (but not official) standard implementation. Several languages like have adopted it to their needs as well. I am actually trying to make the Delphi and C++Builder people at Embarcadero adopt it too. -- Oh wait, you are the guy from Exploring Binary? Good job! Love your site.

Answer (score 7):

There's been a lot of work on printing floating-point numbers.  The gold standard is to print out a decimal equivalent of minimal length such that when the decimal equivalent is read back in, you get the same floating-point number that you started with, no matter what the rounding mode is during readback.   You can read about the algorithm in the excellent [paper by Burger and Dybvig](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.72.4656&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

Comment: That's a well-researched problem that's in some ways simpler and in some ways more difficult, but regardless it's a different problem. Thanks for the link though.

Comment: @R: Oops.  I failed to understand the question.  Perhaps an example would have helped.

Answer (score 3):

Although it's C# and your question is tagged with C, Jon Skeet has code to convert a `double` to its exact representation as a string: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/DoubleConverter.cs

From a quick glance, it does not appear to be too hard to port to C, and even easier to write in C++.

Upon further reflection, it appears that Jon's algorithm is also O(e^2), as it also loops over the exponent. However, that means the algorithm is O(log(n)^2) (where n is the floating-point number), and I'm not sure you can convert from base 2 to base 10 in better than log-squared time.

Comment: Interesting.  Looks like he took that BCD approach, or close to it.

Comment: That is the same method he mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Kaestur: Yes, but the code shows how to handle the fringe cases, such as subnormals.  It's worth looking at.

Comment: If you're considering the theoretical big-O (and bignum stuff), then conversion from base 2 to base 10 probably can't be done in less than log-squared time. But if your numbers fit in machine words, it's log time, which is much better. The question is whether you can do the same thing for floating point numbers using the machine's floating point arithmetic.

Comment: My implementation used the ugly loop (rather than bit fiddling) to extract the mantissa, so it didn't care if the floating point value was subnormal to begin with. `for (e=0; x<1; x*=2, e--);` brought it into normal range in a few iterations.

Answer (score 2):

Well being no floating point expert myself, I'd defer to using a well tested open source library.

The [GNU MPFR](http://www.mpfr.org/) is a good one.

> The MPFR library is a C library for
>   multiple-precision floating-point
>   computations with correct rounding.
>   The main goal of MPFR is to provide a
>   library for multiple-precision
>   floating-point computation which is
>   both efficient and has a well-defined
>   semantics.

Comment: And it does support conversion from double to arbitrary decimal.

Answer (score 1):

> sprintf and similar functions are
>   usually only specified up to a number
>   of significant digits to uniquely
>   determine the original floating point
>   value; they don't necessarily print
>   the exact decimal representation.

You can ask for more significant digits than the default:

```
printf("%.100g\n", 0.1);
```

prints `0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625`.

Comment: Your system's printf happens to do the polite (but not specified by any standard) thing and compute as many digits as requested. Most just chop everything off after computing sufficiently many digits to uniquely determine the float. See the links in Rick Regan's answer.

Comment: this works in gcc(gnu compiler collection) and tcc(tiny c compiler)

Comment: @barlop whether this works or not depends on the implementation of the standard library (e.g. glibc), and not the compiler.

Comment: @kikones34 though I suppose that a particular compiler uses  particular implementations of standard libraries. So it does depend on the compiler because the compiler depends on whatever implementations of standard libraries it uses.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 ways

1. **printing numbers in `bin` or `hex`**

   This is the most precise way. I prefer `hex` because it is more like base `10` for reading/feel like for example `F.8h = 15.5` no precision loss here.
2. **printing in `dec` but only the relevant digits**

   With this I mean only digits which can have `1` in your number represented as close as possible.

   `num` of **integer digits** are easy and precise (no precision loss):

   ```
   // n10 - base 10 integer digits
   // n2  - base 2 integer digits
   n10=log10(2^n2)
   n10=log2(2^n2)/log2(10)
   n10=n2/log2(10)
   n10=ceil(n2*0.30102999566398119521373889472449)
   // if fist digit is 0 and n10 > 1 then n10--
   ```

   `num` of **fractional digits** are more tricky and empirically I found this:

   ```
   // n10 - base 10 fract. digits
   // n2  - base 2 fract. digits >= 8
   n10=0; if (n02==8) n10=1;
   else if (n02==9) n10=2;
   else if (n02> 9)
       {
       n10=((n02-9)%10);
            if (n10>=6) n10=2;
       else if (n10>=1) n10=1;
       n10+=2+(((n02-9)/10)*3);
       }
   ```

   if you make a dependency table `n02 <-> n10` then you see that constant `0.30102999566398119521373889472449` is still present, but at start from 8 bits because less cannot represent `0.1` with satisfactory precision (`0.85 - 1.15`). because of negative exponents of base `2` the dependency is not linear, instead it patterns. This code works for small bit count (`<=52`) but at larger bit counts there can be error because used pattern do not fit `log10(2)` or `1/log2(10)` exactly.

   for larger bit counts I use this:

   ```
   n10=7.810+(9.6366363636363636363636*((n02>>5)-1.0));
   ```

   but that formula is 32bit aligned !!! and also bigger bit count ads error to it

   **P.S.** further analysis of binary representation of decadic numbers

   ```
   0.1
   0.01
   0.001
   0.0001
   ...
   ```

   may reveal the exact pattern repetition which would lead to exact number of relevant digits for any bit count.

   for clarity:

   ```
   8 bin digits -> 1 dec digits
   9 bin digits -> 2 dec digits
   10 bin digits -> 3 dec digits
   11 bin digits -> 3 dec digits
   12 bin digits -> 3 dec digits
   13 bin digits -> 3 dec digits
   14 bin digits -> 3 dec digits
   15 bin digits -> 4 dec digits
   16 bin digits -> 4 dec digits
   17 bin digits -> 4 dec digits
   18 bin digits -> 4 dec digits
   19 bin digits -> 5 dec digits
   20 bin digits -> 6 dec digits
   21 bin digits -> 6 dec digits
   22 bin digits -> 6 dec digits
   23 bin digits -> 6 dec digits
   24 bin digits -> 6 dec digits
   25 bin digits -> 7 dec digits
   26 bin digits -> 7 dec digits
   27 bin digits -> 7 dec digits
   28 bin digits -> 7 dec digits
   29 bin digits -> 8 dec digits
   30 bin digits -> 9 dec digits
   31 bin digits -> 9 dec digits
   32 bin digits -> 9 dec digits
   33 bin digits -> 9 dec digits
   34 bin digits -> 9 dec digits
   35 bin digits -> 10 dec digits
   36 bin digits -> 10 dec digits
   37 bin digits -> 10 dec digits
   38 bin digits -> 10 dec digits
   39 bin digits -> 11 dec digits
   40 bin digits -> 12 dec digits
   41 bin digits -> 12 dec digits
   42 bin digits -> 12 dec digits
   43 bin digits -> 12 dec digits
   44 bin digits -> 12 dec digits
   45 bin digits -> 13 dec digits
   46 bin digits -> 13 dec digits
   47 bin digits -> 13 dec digits
   48 bin digits -> 13 dec digits
   49 bin digits -> 14 dec digits
   50 bin digits -> 15 dec digits
   51 bin digits -> 15 dec digits
   52 bin digits -> 15 dec digits
   53 bin digits -> 15 dec digits
   54 bin digits -> 15 dec digits
   55 bin digits -> 16 dec digits
   56 bin digits -> 16 dec digits
   57 bin digits -> 16 dec digits
   58 bin digits -> 16 dec digits
   59 bin digits -> 17 dec digits
   60 bin digits -> 18 dec digits
   61 bin digits -> 18 dec digits
   62 bin digits -> 18 dec digits
   63 bin digits -> 18 dec digits
   64 bin digits -> 18 dec digits
   ```

   And at last do not forget to round the cut off digits !!! That means if digit after the last relevant digit is `>=5` in dec than last relevant digit should be `+1` ... and if it is already `9` than you must go to previous digit and so on...
3. **print exact value**

   To print exact value of **fractional binary number** just print fractional `n` digits where `n` is the number of fractional bits because the value represented is sum of this values so the number of **fractional decimals** cannot be bigger than the `num` of fractional digits of **LSB**. Stuff above (bullet **#2**) is relevant for storing decimal number to `float` (or printing just relevant decimals).

   negative powers of two exact values...

   ```
   2^- 1 = 0.5
   2^- 2 = 0.25
   2^- 3 = 0.125
   2^- 4 = 0.0625
   2^- 5 = 0.03125
   2^- 6 = 0.015625
   2^- 7 = 0.0078125
   2^- 8 = 0.00390625
   2^- 9 = 0.001953125
   2^-10 = 0.0009765625
   2^-11 = 0.00048828125
   2^-12 = 0.000244140625
   2^-13 = 0.0001220703125
   2^-14 = 0.00006103515625
   2^-15 = 0.000030517578125
   2^-16 = 0.0000152587890625
   2^-17 = 0.00000762939453125
   2^-18 = 0.000003814697265625
   2^-19 = 0.0000019073486328125
   2^-20 = 0.00000095367431640625
   ```

   now negative powers of `10` printed by exact value style for 64 bit `doubles`:

   ```
   10^+ -1 = 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625
           = 0.0001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001101b
   10^+ -2 = 0.01000000000000000020816681711721685132943093776702880859375
           = 0.00000010100011110101110000101000111101011100001010001111011b
   10^+ -3 = 0.001000000000000000020816681711721685132943093776702880859375
           = 0.000000000100000110001001001101110100101111000110101001111111b
   10^+ -4 = 0.000100000000000000004792173602385929598312941379845142364501953125
           = 0.000000000000011010001101101110001011101011000111000100001100101101b
   10^+ -5 = 0.000010000000000000000818030539140313095458623138256371021270751953125
           = 0.000000000000000010100111110001011010110001000111000110110100011110001b
   10^+ -6 = 0.000000999999999999999954748111825886258685613938723690807819366455078125
           = 0.000000000000000000010000110001101111011110100000101101011110110110001101b
   10^+ -7 = 0.0000000999999999999999954748111825886258685613938723690807819366455078125
           = 0.0000000000000000000000011010110101111111001010011010101111001010111101001b
   10^+ -8 = 0.000000010000000000000000209225608301284726753266340892878361046314239501953125
           = 0.000000000000000000000000001010101111001100011101110001000110000100011000011101b
   10^+ -9 = 0.0000000010000000000000000622815914577798564188970686927859787829220294952392578125
           = 0.0000000000000000000000000000010001001011100000101111101000001001101101011010010101b
   10^+-10 = 0.00000000010000000000000000364321973154977415791655470655996396089904010295867919921875
           = 0.00000000000000000000000000000000011011011111001101111111011001110101111011110110111011b
   10^+-11 = 0.00000000000999999999999999939496969281939810930172340963650867706746794283390045166015625
           = 0.00000000000000000000000000000000000010101111111010111111111100001011110010110010010010101b
   10^+-12 = 0.00000000000099999999999999997988664762925561536725284350612952266601496376097202301025390625
           = 0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000010001100101111001100110000001001011011110101000010001b
   10^+-13 = 0.00000000000010000000000000000303737455634003709136034716842278413651001756079494953155517578125
           = 0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000001110000100101110000100110100001001001011101101000001b
   10^+-14 = 0.000000000000009999999999999999988193093545598986971343290729163921781719182035885751247406005859375
           = 0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010110100001001001101110000110101000010010101110011011b
   10^+-15 = 0.00000000000000100000000000000007770539987666107923830718560119501514549256171449087560176849365234375
           = 0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001001000000011101011111001111011100111010101100001011b
   10^+-16 = 0.00000000000000009999999999999999790977867240346035618411149408467364363417573258630000054836273193359375
           = 0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000111001101001010110010100101111101100010001001101111b
   10^+-17 = 0.0000000000000000100000000000000007154242405462192450852805618492324772617063644020163337700068950653076171875
           = 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010111000011101111010101000110010001101101010010010111b
   10^+-18 = 0.00000000000000000100000000000000007154242405462192450852805618492324772617063644020163337700068950653076171875
           = 0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100100111001001011101110100011101001001000011101011b
   10^+-19 = 0.000000000000000000099999999999999997524592683526013185572915905567688179926555402943222361500374972820281982421875
           = 0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000111011000001111001001010011111011011011010010101011b
   10^+-20 = 0.00000000000000000000999999999999999945153271454209571651729503702787392447107715776066783064379706047475337982177734375
           = 0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010111100111001010000100001100100100100100001000100011b
   ```

   now negative powers of 10 printed by relevant decimal digits only style (i am more used to this) for 64bit `doubles`:

   ```
   10^+ -1 = 0.1
   10^+ -2 = 0.01
   10^+ -3 = 0.001
   10^+ -4 = 0.0001
   10^+ -5 = 0.00001
   10^+ -6 = 0.000001
   10^+ -7 = 0.0000001
   10^+ -8 = 0.00000001
   10^+ -9 = 0.000000001
   10^+-10 = 0.0000000001
   10^+-11 = 0.00000000001
   10^+-12 = 0.000000000001
   10^+-13 = 0.0000000000001
   10^+-14 = 0.00000000000001
   10^+-15 = 0.000000000000001
   10^+-16 = 0.0000000000000001
   10^+-17 = 0.00000000000000001
   10^+-18 = 0.000000000000000001
   10^+-19 = 0.0000000000000000001
   10^+-20 = 0.00000000000000000001
   ```

   hope it helps :)

Comment: This answer is is very interesting (so please don't delete it, it might be helpful to somebody who comes along with a slightly different problem) but it doesn't answer this question. This question is about printing the exact value, not printing sufficiently many digits to recover the original value by rounding.

Comment: binary fractions cannot be converted to decimal fractions without precision loss (in finite digits count) so if you want to print exact value than the point 1. is relevant only (print numbers in hex/bin or any base decomposable by power of 2). i wass thinking you want to print exact decimal value storable in floating point (in given mantisa precision)  and not exact floating point value stored in floating point as decimal number. sorry ... still point 1 answers your question (you did not specify decadic system) for example 1.6A09E667F3BCC908B2FB1366h is sqrt(2) in hex

Comment: Yes they can. For example, a binary fraction of 0.01 is decimal 0.25, and a binary fraction of 0.001 is decimal 0.125. In general, the number of decimal places to the right of the decimal point is equal to the number of binary places to the right of the binary point.

Comment: Silly me ... i was thinking it backwards again :) that came for transform base10 -> base2 ... in print it is base2 -> base10 thats easy num of decimal digits is exactly the same as num of fractional digits see my answer ... for edit

Comment: btw i forgot to tell:  to eliminate precission loss during conversion bin -> dec i create hex string (simple shift+and of mantisa in a loop) and then i convert this hex string to dec string (then reformat and print). my conversion code is here (no use of bignums or FPU) http://stackoverflow.com/a/18231860/2521214

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE this [32 bit float print on integer math only](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59861545/2521214) might interest you

Answer (score -1):

If you want more exact results, why not use fixed point math instead?  Conversions are quick.  Error is known and can be worked around.  Not an exact answer to your question, but a different idea for you.

Comment: Wouldn't be a bad idea if I were using this in a specific application, but the problem domain is specifically solving this (rather painful) floating point to exact decimal conversion.

Answer (score -1):

Off the top of my head, why not break the exponent down into a sum of binary exponents first, then all your operations are loss-less.

I.e.

```
10^2 = 2^6 + 2^5 + 2^2
```

Then sum:

```
mantissa<<6 + mantissa<<5 + mantissa<<2
```

I'm thinking that breaking it down would be on the O(n) on the the number of digits, the shifting is O(1), and the summing is O(n) digits...

You would have to have an integer class big enough to store the results, of course...

Let me know - I'm curious about this, it really made me think. :-)

Comment: The exponent is a binary exponent to begin with. And there's definitely no integer type (without some sort of bigint) capable of storing the result. It can be over 1000 digits with a double, and over 16000 digits with a long double. :-)

Comment: @r: i guess you could calloc(1000) and then bit-copy things in the right place. but definitely messy. floating point is there for a reason. :-)

Comment: this can work only for integer part of number and there are much faster easier and nicer ways for it ... look at my answer for log2(10) which is pretty constant ... so if you want num of dec integer digits than n(base10) = n(base2)/log2(10). the problem is that this question is all about fractional part which cant be decomposed to powers of 2 ... at least i havent a clue how 10^-n = 2^-a+2^-b+2^-c+... the only way is to round it to the closest match within given accuracy

Answer (score -3):

You don't.  The closest you can come to that is dumping the bytes.

Comment: I've thought about this some more, and I think I'm wrong.  Since base 10 goes into base 2, there shouldn't be any binary values that can only be represented in decimal if we allow repeating digits.  As a result, you should in principle be able to convert a float/double to a (potentially very long) string of decimal digits.

Comment: Of course you can. I have an implementation that does it in `O(e^2)` time (which hopefully can be improved) and `O(e)` space (which the decimal representation necessarily requires) as I described.

Comment: To finish answering, yes, the algorithm you described looks like it would work, but an arbitrary precision library (like the one Byron recommended) would make things easy.  For something related but I think different, there's also: http://keithbriggs.info/xrc.html

Comment: I suspect that implementing the multiplications as shifts will speed things up, but that doesn't necessarily improve the big O.

Comment: I think what i just wrote is wrong, because I missed out on the fact that the doubling is happening to the decimal value.  Perhaps the way to handle this is to keep the output in a format like BCD until you're done.

Comment: You can definitely store several decimal digits in each array position; in fact it should work to use 32bit integers to store values up to 1 billion as long as you handle the carry/remainder right. The big-O doesn't improve but the constant is slashed by a factor of 9. At the end, normal integer printing of each 32bit cell can be performed.

Comment: Skeet's code takes the compromise of 1 digit per byte, as opposed to the 2 that BCD would bring.  While he loses compactness, he significantly simplifies the implementation of operations such as shifting and multiplying, so it might be worth it.  It's better than the usual BigNumber solution of using a character for each, because you avoid having to mask and unmask the 48.

Comment: I was reading http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal, which gives the algorithm for adding BCD values.  You could perform a doubling simply by adding the value to itself.  Essentially, you do a binary add and then adjust it back to BCD.  This could be faster than digit-by-digit adding.

Comment: This is a link to an explanation of the algorithm used by the old ASM instruction, DAA: http://faydoc.tripod.com/cpu/daa.htm.  At first glance, it looks like it could be scaled up, with a table implementation that implements carry by returning values twice as wide as the input.

Comment: I think I'm out of ideas, although I've done enough to repent for my original mistake.  I do want to point out that, even though this prints the precise decimal equivalent of the float, the float itself may not have been initialized with precise equivalents of the decimal, and even if it was, then operations on it may well have generated repeating digits and other artifacts.  If you really want a precise answer, something  like xrc is the way to go.  Good luck.

Comment: This answer was downvoted sometime after it was originally written as part of a pattern of arbitrary downvotes.