# How to Output a Double Value with all the Decimal Places in Debugger or Console

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I wish to extract `double` value completely when I am debugging an application, so that I can use it to construct a test case to feed into my geometry algorithm.

How to extract the `double` value out-- down to very last decimal places allowed by the `double` datatypes in C#-- and output it in either debugger windows, or using `Console.WriteLine` command?

Edit: My problem is that the algorithm that takes the double value as input will only fail if I insist of input the whole double value, right down to the very last digit. And since I want to reproduce it in a test case, that's why I would need such a full representation of the double value.

Comment: What happens when you use `Console.WriteLine`?

Comment: @Drackir, it only shows up to 10 decimal places for my test case, even though it has more than 30++ decimal places.

Answer (score 2):

I have a [DoubleConverter class](http://yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/DoubleConverter.cs) which does *exactly* what you want, by the sounds of it. Use it like this:

```
string text = DoubleConverter.ToExactString(doubleValue);
```

You need to make sure you understand that just because the output has a large number of digits, that doesn't mean it has that much *precision*. You may want to read my article on [binary floating point in .NET](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx) for more information - or you may be aware of all of this to start with, of course.

Note that if you only want a string value which can be round-tripped, you don't need any extra code - just use the "r" format specifier:

```
string text = doubleValue.ToString("r");
```

I agree with Jackson Pope's general approach of using tolerance in equality comparisons for tests, but I do find it useful sometimes to see the exact value represented by a double. It can make it easier to understand why a particular calculation has come out one way or another.

Comment: it really amazes me that C# can't get it done, and we have to resort to writing our own class to handle it.

Comment: @Graviton: Well C# doesn't specify much about this at all... you're more bothered by the .NET library. And it's not *that* common a requirement - because usually you *should* be interested in the general magnitude rather than the exact value beyond the available precision.

Comment: I've tested your code-- and I'm not too sure it works. Here's my test code: `double aat = 23445.4364487567676445433642536544656;string text = DoubleConverter.ToExactString(aat);Console.WriteLine(text);', and the string I got is `"23445.43644875676909578032791614532470703125"`. They are not the same.

Comment: my problem is that the algorithm that takes the double value as input will only fail if I insist of input the whole double value, right down to the very last digit.

Comment: Parsing these two strings representing Double number, "23445.4364487567676445433642536544656" and "23445.43644875676909578032791614532470703125", into Double value gives exactly same value. I have tested this by evaluating System.Double.Parse("23445.4364487567676445433642536544656").ToString("r") for both cases. So DoubleConverter is working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to output a binary number as a decimal number to a very large number of decimal places and do an exact comparison, instead do a comparison with an epsilon value that is your acceptable error and set epsilon to be very small. E.g.

```
 double epsilon = Math.Abs(actual - expected);
 Assert.That(epsilon, Is.LessThan(0.000000000001);
```

Comment: For many applications, what you suggest is best. I am in the same boat as the OP. I have a numerical algorithm that goes into an infinite loop for rare cases. When the problem pops up, I halt in the debugger and inspect the input parameters. However, when I make an NUnit case using these values, it does not loop infinitely. VS is rounding the result and the rounded values do not exhibit the problem.