# Data mismatches when reading and writing to a wav file

Tags: c++, audio, libsndfile

I am working on a audio using the libsndfile library. First, I have loaded my data from an existing wav file and then I stored those data into an `std::vector`. Next, I passed those data to `sf_write_float` but before I opened the new file with this function `sf_open` in write mode and store the data in that new file into a new `std::vector`.

The following is a function that writes:

```
SF_INFO sfInfo;
sfInfo.samplerate = sampleRate;
sfInfo.channels = nbrChannels;
sfInfo.format = SF_FORMAT_WAV | SF_FORMAT_FLOAT;

SNDFILE* sndFile = sf_open(path.c_str(), SFM_WRITE, &sfInfo);
if (sndFile == nullptr) {
     std::cout << sf_strerror(sndFile);
}

sf_count_t count = sf_write_float(sndFile, samples.data(), samples.size());

sf_write_sync(sndFile);
sf_close(sndFile);
```

And this the function to read:

```
SF_INFO input;
SNDFILE* infile;

infile = sf_open(filePath.c_str(), SFM_READ, &input);
if (infile == nullptr) {
     std::cout << sf_strerror(infile);
}

float audio[input.channels * input.frames];
sf_read_float(infile, audio, input.channels * input.frames);
```

I was expecting to get similar data for both vectors but they are slightly different (difference of 10^-4).

Can someone explain this?

NB: I inspected the samplerate, the frames, the channels, the format, the sections and the seekable fields and they all are the same.

Comment: `float audio[input.channels * input.frames];` is invalid C++ (VLA extension), use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: `std::vector<float> audio; audioIn.reserve(input.channels * input.frames);` did this but still the same thing

Comment: How did you compare the values? Printing and eyeballing?

Comment: @Botje, I print them to a csv file and get the delta

Comment: Very probably the printing process introduced some rounding artefacts. Show that code.

Comment: @Botje, how can I know that? I need to argument that

Comment: See [this question, for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324034/write-a-float-with-full-precision-in-c), of how naively printing a float may result in different numbers. If you wanted to be sure the numbers are identical, compare the bit patterns instead.

Comment: @Botje, even if I do not print those data to a file and just CHECK(vec1 == vec2), it fails.

Comment: Then the next step is to look at the bit patterns and see by how much the individual values differ. It is entirely possible that libsndfile does some internal conversions that are _mathematically_ a no-op, but result in inaccuracies due to the way floating point numbers work in computers. As a very silly example of this, see [this question about why 0.1 + 0.2 != 0.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: @Botje, I am not familiar with bit patterns, how can I do that?

Comment: Use your debugger's memory explorer or the `%a` printf qualifier that was mentioned in the question I linked