# Printing Big Numbers in Decimal Form

Tags: c, algorithm, numbers, printf, gmp

Though the representations of a number are somewhat a relative aspect, we
generally use the decimal form when printing to the outer world.

I'm in a Mac OS X, and while analyzing the source of libc I found that the
famous `printf` function ends up calling a little function `__ultoa` — after
going through `vfprintf_l`, the 1104 lines `__vfprintf` and finally `__ultoa`.
It's defined as follows (in this case all these come straight from FreeBSD):

```
/*
 * Convert an unsigned long to ASCII for printf purposes, returning
 * a pointer to the first character of the string representation.
 * Octal numbers can be forced to have a leading zero; hex numbers
 * use the given digits.
 */
static CHAR *
__ultoa(u_long val, CHAR *endp, int base, int octzero, const char *xdigs)
{
    CHAR *cp = endp;
    long sval;

    /*
     * Handle the three cases separately, in the hope of getting
     * better/faster code.
     */
    switch (base) {
    case 10:
        if (val < 10) {     /* many numbers are 1 digit */
            *--cp = to_char(val);
            return (cp);
        }
        /*
         * On many machines, unsigned arithmetic is harder than
         * signed arithmetic, so we do at most one unsigned mod and
         * divide; this is sufficient to reduce the range of
         * the incoming value to where signed arithmetic works.
         */
        if (val > LONG_MAX) {
            *--cp = to_char(val % 10);
            sval = val / 10;
        } else
            sval = val;
        do {
            *--cp = to_char(sval % 10);
            sval /= 10;
        } while (sval != 0);
        break;

    case 8:
        do {
            *--cp = to_char(val & 7);
            val >>= 3;
        } while (val);
        if (octzero && *cp != '0')
            *--cp = '0';
        break;

    case 16:
        do {
            *--cp = xdigs[val & 15];
            val >>= 4;
        } while (val);
        break;

    default:                /* oops */
        LIBC_ABORT("__ultoa: invalid base=%d", base);
    }
    return (cp);
}
```

Here `CHAR` is just typedef'ed to `char` (for some reason) and `to_char` does
basically what you'd expect:

```
#define to_char(n)  ((n) + '0')
```

The translation to the decimal form occurs in a straightforward way, dividing by
10 and taking %10:

```
do {
    *--cp = to_char(sval % 10);
    sval /= 10;
} while (sval != 0);
```

However, while this work for little numbers (up to 8 bytes) it seems too much
"manual labor" for me. In GMP, you can easily calculate 2<sup>5000</sup>:

```
mpz_t n;
mpz_init(n);
mpz_ui_pow_ui(n, 2ul, 5000ul);
gmp_printf("%Zd\n", n);
```

While this has an easy representation for bases 2 or 16, the decimal form is a
bit harder to calculate.

So, how exactly libraries like GMP handles these? Looks like taking modulo and
divisions can be expensive for such big numbers. Is there any faster algorithm,
or am I wrong and the standard process is easy for computers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard process is not easy, but one way or another you need to do the equivalent operations to obtain the decimal digits, and this can involve high-precision arithmetic even if the original value in binary is just a few bits or a single bit. See my question:

[How do you print the EXACT value of a floating point number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215235/how-do-you-print-the-exact-value-of-a-floating-point-number)

It's about floating point, but all large floating point numbers are integers anyway, and the very-large and very-small cases are the only interesting cases.

Comment: Thanks R.., that's really helpful —and I see there is a lot to read in the subject. Then I might be ready to print the power of two which represents the amount of atoms in our universe by myself :-)