# How many Binary Digits needed for X Decimal Digits of Square Root of 2

Tags: math, square-root

I've been playing around with calculating the square root of 2 and the like. It's easy to come up with an algorithm that will produce n correct binary digits. What I'd like help with is determining how many binary digits I need to get m correct decimal digits? m Binary digits will get me m Decimal digits, but the m decimal digits may not all be correct yet.

---

**EDIT:**
I've determined that the lower bound on the binary `precision = ceil(log2(10^m))`.

Thinking about it there might not be a strict upper-bound, since a carry from any lower power of 2 (when converting to base 10) could potentially effect any higher digit base 10.

This may thus be a dynamic problem that requires evaluating the fractional expansion at m binary digits and determining which additional binary digits could potentially cause a carry in base 10.

---

**Edit 2:** I was probably overthinking this. After the initial calculation I can keep adding (1x10^(-precision)) and squaring the result until I exceed 2 - and then subtract (1x10^(-precision)) and I'll have my answer. Nevertheless I am still interested in finding/developing such an algorithm **:)**

Comment: You mean precision = ceil(log2(10^-m)) with a minus in front of m, isn'it?

Comment: m represents the number of digits (positive). if m = 5 decimal digits, then I need at least a precision = ceil(log2(10^5)) = 17. 

On the other hand, ceil(log2(10^-5)) = -16, which is not what I want. Id need to change the equation to -floor(log2(10^-m)).

Of course, without the leading negative sign, the latter equation gives you a negative precision value - which might be preferable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let x be a real and y be its approximation.

Let RE be the relative error of y with respect to x:

RE(x, y) = abs(x - y) / abs(x)

Let b be a nonnegative integer. The Log-Relative Error in base b is defined as:

LREb(x, y) = -logb(RE(x, y))

where logb is the base-b logarithm:

logb(z) = log(z) / log(b)

for any nonnegative z.

The LRE in base b represents the number of common digits between x and y. Here, the "number of correct digits" is not an integer, but a real number: this will simplify the next calculations avoiding the need for ceil and floor functions, provided that we accept statements such as : "y has 2.3 correct digits with respect to x". More precisely, if x and y have q common base b digits, then:

LREb(x, y) >= q - 1

With these equation, if the relative error has an upper bound, then the LREb has a lower bound. More precisely, if:

RE(x, y) <= epsilon

then:

LREb(x, y) >= -logb(epsilon)

Also, if the number of correct digits in base 10 is LRE10 = p, then RE = 10^-p, which implies that the number of correct digits in base 2 is:

LRE2 = -log2(10^-p)

Comment: It seems like to be able to use these equations, however, you need to know x before you can evaluate the approximation y. Granted the square root of 2 has been published to like 10 trillion decimal digits; but I'd prefer an approach that doesn't require having the actual value (to so many digits) in order to determine if the estimate is correct

Comment: In order to estimate the LRE from the exact value x and its approximation y, you need indeed, to know the value of x. This is what we commonly do to assess the quality of an algorithm on a validation test case with a known exact solution x. However, you do not necessarily need to know x: knowing the relative error is sufficient. This can be done if the algorithm we use guarantees a known relative error.

Comment: I see. I will have to study up more on this. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

what method you are using?

I am assuming binary search of `x` in `y = x^2`

**integer part** is limited by the result `sqrt(y)` and cannot be cut otherwise result would be wrong. However the `x` is limited by half the bits of `y` so:

```
ni2 = log2(|y|)
```

**fractional part** is tricky see:

- [the relation between binary and decimal digits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18401040/2521214)

but after the nonlinear start of first digits the dependence stabilizes here reversed formula from linked answer:

```
nf2 = (((nf10-7.810)/9.6366363636363636363636)+1.0)<<5;
```

- `ni2` is integer part binary bits/digits
- `nf2` is fractional part binary bits/digits
- `nf10` is fractional part decadic digits

btw I used 32 bit aligned values as that is what I use for my arithmetics so:

```
9.6366363636363636363636 = 32/0.30102999566398119521373889472449
0.30102999566398119521373889472449 = log10(2)
```

Comment: I developed my own integer square root algorithm. I'm then calculating integer_sqrt(2^(p+1)). If needed, you can divide by 2^p to put it into a fractional format.

Comment: Edit: integer_sqrt(2^(2p + 1))

Comment: @RyanPierceWilliams You might like to take a look at this: [How to get a square root for 32 bit input in one clock cycle only?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34657972/2521214) mine is 16T but still a beauty without any higher math operations not even multiply

Comment: That looks like an interesting algorithm :) I'm sticking with my own sqrt algorithm that I developed for the purposes of my research (much better than a binary search), but I could see applications where that algorithm could be beneficial