# Is there any way to have a large number display in full, as opposed to using scientific notation?

Tags: javascript

For example, if I produce the factorial of 100 and store it in this way using JavaScript:

```
function factorial (num) {
    if (num == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    else     {
        return num * factorial(num - 1);
    }
}

var result = factorial(100);
```

`console.log(result)` will then produce `9.33262154439441e+157`.

Is there a way to have it display in full?

As a string would be fine, but `result.toString()` literally produces `"9.33262154439441e+157"`.

If there's some way to imitate `charAt()` for numbers, iterating over each digit and concatenating them as a string would become an option.

All in all, is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Use a string for `num`, and do the multiplication one character at a time (from right to left). Don't forget about carrying.

Comment: That's almost as many "good" digits as you can get out of a double-precision floating point number when expressed in decimal. Most of the 158 digits are not really there.

Comment: If what you want is processing really large numbers indeed, check [this library](https://github.com/jtobey/javascript-bignum). I wonder, though, ain't you looking for something else to do with that 100! value...

Comment: @raina77ow - Thanks for the help; in actual fact, I'm trying to find the sum of the digits in very large numbers. The library looks interesting, I'll try it out. Thank you.

Comment: But that's another question, don't you think? And it's already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469529/sum-of-digits-of-a-factorial). Obviously, you don't have to compute `100!` to find the sum of its digits, that would be rather trivial.

Comment: @raina77ow - Yes, most likely. I just wanted to ask this question, because I thought it would be something of use to know if I ran into a similar problem again.